# C++ factoral function returning inf

Tags: c++

so I am writing a C++ program that is meant to get the factoral of a number, but when I pass a large number into it, it returns with "inf", I've tried to add an if statement to check if it is larger than the max size of the data type, being a long double, which doesn't solve this. Can someone help? thanks. Here is my code:

```
long double factoral(long double num)
{
    if (num >= std::numeric_limits<long double>::max() || num < std::numeric_limits<long double>::min())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (num > 1)
    {
        return num * factoral(num - 1);
    }

    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long double res = factoral(1000);

    if (res == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "The factoral of 1000 is either too large or too small";
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "The factoral of 1000: " << res;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Stirling's formula gives an approximation of factorial: `sqrt(2nPi) (n/e)^n`. Try to evaluate it by hand and compare with max admitted value

Comment: the factorial from 1 to 1000 is around 10^2600, which is way to big for a long double

Comment: The argument will never overflow (you first pass 1000, which isn't "large", then smaller and smaller numbers until you reach 1). It is the result that overflows.

Comment: on this platform the result is not too big: http://cpp.sh/2z4p4 . it depends on platform/compiler

Comment: It's also unclear why you use a recursive call when a simple for loop would do the job.

Comment: A factorial is one of the goto examples for recursion is likely why.

Answer (score 2):

your result get overflowed (`inf`) at `return num * factoral(num - 1);` so you only have to check limits around there, like below.

```cpp
long double factoral(long double num) {

    if (num > 1) {
        long double ret = num * factoral(num - 1);
        if (ret >= std::numeric_limits<long double>::max())
            return 0;
        return ret;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I also recommend you to have an iterative solution something like (untested code)

```
long long fac(long long num) {
    long long ret = 1;
    while (num--) ret *= num; //< handle limits here
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: [std::isfinite](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite)

Comment: Thank you, I seem to have got the error sorted with thakee nathees code, thanks for the help & info, guys